# Can I play a land on my opponent's turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I was playing MtG Commander with a group of 4 and I was 3rd in turn order. We were wondering about casting a land that would enter tapped on an enemies endstep or second main phase, so it could untap on their turn? For example let’s say player 2 goes to end step, would I be able to cast a [Drowned Catacomb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Drowned%20Catacomb) if I didn’t play a land on my previous turn, or would it have to happen on their second main phase?

Answer (score 9):

No, that won't work. You can't play lands on other players' turns.

You don't cast lands like a spell, you *play* lands. Playing lands is a special action that you can only perform during one of your own main phases and when the stack is empty.

I would recommend you and your playgroup read the [Basic Rulebook](https://magic.wizards.com/en/how-to-play).

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast lands, only play them, and you can only play lands on your turn, during your main phase, when nobody is casting any other spell ("the stack is empty").

*However*, you can put a land into play on your opponent's turn if an effect lets you do it, e.g. if you cast [Growth Spiral](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Growth%20Spiral) on your opponent's turn, it would let you put a land into play on their turn.

Comment: Technically speaking, Growth Spiral does not allow you to play a land. It allows you to put a land from your hand onto the battlefield. This can be an important distinction, since cards that allow you to play a card still don't allow you to play a land when it isn't your turn due to rule 305.3. "A player can’t play a land, for any reason, if it isn’t their turn. Ignore any part of an effect that instructs a player to do so."